# how to set trusted proxies for laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Quoting https://laravel-news.com/trusted-proxy

> You can create the config/trustedproxy.php configuration by running vendor:publish:
>
> ```
> php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Fideloper\Proxy\TrustedProxyServiceProvider"
> ```

I did that and altho it said "Publishing complete." I'm not seeing a config/trustedproxy.php file...

I did `grep -r Fideloper .` and that did not return any results either...

I'm running Laravel 5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::setTrustedProxies(['0.0.0.0/0']);` to index.php and that seemed to do the trick. I'm sure it's not the "proper" solution but it works!